# Kusto Query Language - Round datetime to nearest month using bin

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have plenty of logs with its own timestamp, and I am trying to count the logs on a monthly basis.

Here is a sample table and query using bin(30d):

```
datatable(Date:datetime, Log:string)[
datetime(2018-02-02T15:14),"log1",
datetime(2018-03-23T12:14),"log2",
datetime(2018-03-24T16:14),"log3",
datetime(2019-04-26T15:14),"log4"]
| summarize count(Log) by bin(Date,30d)
```

The output I want:

```
Date    count_Log
2018-02 00:00:00.0000000    1
2018-03 00:00:00.0000000    2
2019-04 00:00:00.0000000    1
```

The output I get:

```
Date    count_Log
2018-01-17 00:00:00.0000000 1   //see the date, it shows JAN but the log is of Feb
2018-03-18 00:00:00.0000000 2
2019-04-12 00:00:00.0000000 1
```

I need the summary month wise, so How can I do it month wise? I accept the bin size as a parameter of different values like 1h, 1d, 7d, 10d, etc. There is no timespan of 1 month.

So How can I do it without having to extract month/year manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [`startofmonth()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/startofmonthfunction)

for example:

```
datatable(Date: datetime, Log: string)
[
    datetime(2018-02-02T15:14), "log1",
    datetime(2018-03-23T12:14), "log2",
    datetime(2018-03-24T16:14), "log3",
    datetime(2019-04-26T15:14), "log4"
]
| summarize count() by startofmonth(Date)
```

| Column1 | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-02-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 |
| 2018-03-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 2 |
| 2019-04-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 1 |

Comment: The bin is actually a parameter that is passed from a dashboard (geneva), so if i use startofmonth, then I should have that hardcoded to startofmonth always.